# Returning the value of an API request in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am currently trying to make API requests for an app, but I have an issue:

When I make the API request, the first one returns "undefined", but the second one (and all others) returns what I want.

Here is my code:

```
exports.makeRequest = function(infos, setInfos) {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        setInfos(data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    })
    return infos
}
```

And it is called this way in my app:

```
const [infos, setInfos] = useState([])
makeRequest(infos, setInfos);
```

I found out what happens: On the first request, it doesn't go in ".then((data) => {setInfos(data)})"

Comment: Is the last sentence an answer? Or an observation?